# Find Two Closest Solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the two closest solutions to $z=0$ of 
$$e^{e^z}=1$$

I started with setting $t=e^z$

$$e^{t}=1\iff e^t=e^{(0+2\pi k)i}\iff t=2\pi ki$$

so

Because we are on the unit circle every two solution $|f(z_1)|=|f(z_2)|=1$ so we need to take the square root.

$$e^z=\frac{2\pi k i}{2} \text{    Where }   k=0,1$$

$$z=ln|\frac{2\pi k}{2}|=ln|\pi k|$$ for $k=1$ we get $z=ln|\pi|$ when $k=0$ we get $ln|0|$ so we need to take the 3rd root

$z=ln|\frac{2\pi k}{3}|$ for $k=0,1,2$

for $k=1$ we get $ln|\frac{\pi}{3}|$ for $k=1$ we get $ln|\frac{2\pi}{3}| $

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing $e^z = t$ we have $e^t = 1$ so $t=2\pi i k$ with $k$ integer, i.e. $e^z = 2\pi ik$ with $k$ integer. If $k=0$, $e^z=0$ has no solution, so if $k\neq 0$ 
$$
z = \ln|2\pi ik| + \arg(2\pi i k)i = \ln(2\pi |k|) + \arg(2\pi i k)i
$$
Simplifying 
$$
z = \begin{cases}
\ln(2\pi k) + \pi i/2 & k >0\\
\ln(-2\pi k) - \pi i/2 & k<0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: How did we get $\pm \frac{\pi i}{2}$?

Comment: @newhere If $k>0$ then $\arg(2\pi i k) = \pi/2$ (is a pure imaginary number with positive imaginary part). If $k<0$ then $\arg(2\pi i k) = -\pi /2$.